# Laravel Input::flash() How to retrieve flash values

Tags: flash, laravel, redirect, input

Here is my Code to keep form data save.

```
Route::any('test', function(){
    if (Request::isMethod('post')){
        //return Redirect::back()->withInput();
        return Redirect::to('test2')->withInput();
    }
    else {
        return View::make('home');
    }
});
Route::get('test2', function(){
    return var_dump(Input::all());  // Getting Empty Array here.
});
```

I just make a single input with name='email' and post it. When Redirect to another page, its not forwarding inputs using `Redirect::to('test2')->withInput();`

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your Email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am confused, how to use `Input::flash()` or `Redirect::to('test2')->withInput();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exammple:

```
Route::any('test', function(){
        if (Request::isMethod('post')){
            Input::flash();
            return Redirect::back();
            // return Redirect::back()->withInput();
        }
        else {
            if(Input::old('email'))return Input::old(); //::old is only accessible when we did ::flash() or ::withInput()
            return View::make('home');
    }
});
```

To retrieve form data on error etc use

```
Input::old()
```

and Input::old() will **never work without**

```
Redirect::back()->withInput()
```

or

```
Input::flash();
return Redirect::back();
```

**Detail is attached in code as comment**

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Redirect::to()->withInput()` what that does is puts the current state of `Input::all()` into a session variable for later access (it *doesn't* re-submit the input or anything like that). As such, in the new, redirected, request you can't access the same input using `Input:all()` (as it's not re-posted) but now it's under `Input::old()`. Much like a flahs variable, it will only be available for one request too, so if you want to re-flash it you may need to either do `Session::reflash()` or you *may* be able to to `->withInput()` again (though I doubt it, as the new `Input::all()` is empty).

Hopefully that makes sense. Basically your 'test2' route needs to use `Input::old()`.

All that said, it may be that you're doing something not quite right if you're redirecting a POST request to then later handle via `Input::old()` - that's not the real purpose of this construct. Of course, if this is you just playing around with the framework then you're all good to do whatever you want.

Comment: You did work to explain me answer, thanks. I understood what you said. Can you modify your answer with example of using Redirect::to()->withInput() and Input::flash(). I am confused how to return two Redirect:: and also view::Make in single route.

Comment: thanks a lot, good help. it took a little time to understand but did it. +1

Comment: Glad to have helped you come to your own answer.